# Time reference of subordinate clause

Tags: grammaticality

May i request 
to clarify the time references for the following subordinate clauses of the sentence :-
1."He will come to know what i need"or "What i need will be known to him"
2. "He will come to know that i need something "or That i need something will be known to him "
The contexts in both the above are that "I need something in the present (now) which will be known to him in future. 
1.What will be the time reference of subordinate clauses "what i need/That i need something " ? My instinct tells me present time even though the main clause is in future. 
OR will these be Present in the future time examples.
Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand your context, but here's something to think about. Suppose you're a big eater, planning to go to a restaurant later, and you say: *I hope we get that nice waitress again! She'll fill my plate, because she'll know how hungry I **am***. In normal English we use the present tense as highlighted there *regardless of whether the speaker is **currently** hungry* (at time of speaking), even though many other languages might modify for "future" as *...she'll know how hungry I **will be***. Is that relevant to what you're asking?

Comment: Dear Fumblefingers,The contexts in both the above are that "I need something in the present (now) which will be known to him in future. 1

Comment: Even with that extra clarification (which should be made by editing the question, *not* as a potentially short-lived comment), I don't understand exactly what you're asking about. Effectively all I can do is repeat what I already said - the time reference of the highlighted "subordinate clause" in *She'll give me **what I need*** is normally cast in the ***present*** tense, regardless of whether I'm referring to ***something I need now*** (at time of utterance) or something that I ***will*** need at some point in the future (when she gives it to me).

Comment: Dear Fumblefingers, i apologize for the short comment. The present tense aspect of subordinate clause is not in doubt in either case. The doubt is in the applicable time aspect of the subordinating clause restricted to whether it(the present time of subordinate clause ) gets affected by the future time and tense reference of the main clause"He will come to know" or it remains independent of main clause time.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but you're not making things any clearer with that longer comment - in any case, you need to ***edit the question text*** to include any relevant clarification. **IF** you're asking about the difference between, say, *You will like him* and *You will **come to** like him*, you might find [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210965/) relevant..